# Amazon SQS in objective c

Tags: objective-c

Is there any sample code that uses Amazon SQS in objective c code so I can well understand how to use it

Answer (score 2):

Even better, you should be able to link to [Aws4C](http://code.google.com/p/aws4c/) directly from your Objective-C code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find anything for Objective-C, [Amazon::SQS::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~swhitaker/Amazon-SQS-Simple-1.04/MANIFEST) implements the protocol in Perl. The source is fairly instructive - if you can read Perl.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to implement this on an iPhone, please note that Amazon does not take very kindly to mobile usage of its platform (read: Delicious Library for iPhone, among others).

Comment: Why is it so? I have to use it for iPhone app, with Google App Engine

Comment: "(e) You will not, without our express prior written approval requested via  this link , use any Product Advertising Content on or in connection with any site or application designed or intended for use with a mobile phone or other handheld device."

My bad. Sorry for the confusion.